# Unable to verify razorpay signature in hosted checkout PHP

Tags: php, razorpay

i have add **razorpay** test version and payment flow works, but when i try to verify `signature` i get following error

> Notice: Undefined index: razorpay_order_id in C:\Users\Amin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OLX\payment\verify.php on line 24
>   Your payment failed
>
> Razorpay Error : Invalid signature passed

i followed code structure form here https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-php-testapp and am trying to achieve https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/hosted/#step-2---paste-hosted-checkout-options.

can someone point what wrong am going.
here is `verify.php`

```
require('config.php');

session_start();

require('razorpay-php/Razorpay.php');

use Razorpay\Api\Api;
use Razorpay\Api\Errors\SignatureVerificationError;

$success = true;

$error = "Payment Failed";

if (empty($_POST['razorpay_payment_id']) === false) {
    $api = new Api($keyId, $keySecret);

    try {
        // Please note that the razorpay order ID must
        // come from a trusted source (session here, but
        // could be database or something else)
        $attributes = array(
            'razorpay_order_id' => $_SESSION['razorpay_order_id'],
            'razorpay_payment_id' => $_POST['razorpay_payment_id'],
            'razorpay_signature' => $_POST['razorpay_signature']
        );

        $api->utility->verifyPaymentSignature($attributes);
    } catch (SignatureVerificationError $e) {
        $success = false;
        $error = 'Razorpay Error : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if ($success === true) {
    $html = "<p>Your payment was successful</p>
             <p>Payment ID: {$_POST['razorpay_payment_id']}</p>";
} else {
    $html = "<p>Your payment failed</p>
             <p>{$error}</p>";
}

echo $html;
```

here if form post details

```
<form method="POST" action="https://api.razorpay.com/v1/checkout/embedded">
    <input type="hidden" name="key_id" value="<?= $data['key']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?= $data['order_id']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?= $data['name']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="<?= $data['description']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?= $data['image']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="prefill[name]" value="<?= $data['prefill']['name']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="prefill[contact]" value="<?= $data['prefill']['contact']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="prefill[email]" value="<?= $data['prefill']['email']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="notes[shipping address]" value="L-16, The Business Centre, 61 Wellfield Road, New Delhi - 110001">
    <input type="hidden" name="callback_url" value="http://localhost:8000/payment/verify.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="https://example.com/payment-cancel">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

pay.php

```
require('config.php');
require('razorpay-php/Razorpay.php');
session_start();

// Create the Razorpay Order

use Razorpay\Api\Api;

$api = new Api($keyId, $keySecret);

//
// We create an razorpay order using orders api
// Docs: https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/orders
//
$orderData = [
    'receipt'         => 4563,
    'amount'          => 2000 * 100, // 2000 rupees in paise
    'currency'        => 'INR',
    'payment_capture' => 1 // auto capture
];

$razorpayOrder = $api->order->create($orderData);

$razorpayOrderId = $razorpayOrder['id'];

$_SESSION['razorpay_order_id'] = $razorpayOrderId;

$displayAmount = $amount = $orderData['amount'];

if ($displayCurrency !== 'INR'){
    $url = "https://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=$displayCurrency&base=INR";
    $exchange = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

    $displayAmount = $exchange['rates'][$displayCurrency] * $amount / 100;
}

$checkout = 'automatic';

if (isset($_GET['checkout']) and in_array($_GET['checkout'], ['automatic', 'manual'], true))
{
    $checkout = $_GET['checkout'];
}

$data = [
    "key"               => $keyId,
    "amount"            => $amount,
    "name"              => "Sanoj Lawrence",
    "description"       => "safebrowser.tk",
    "image"             => "https://demo-cdn.sirv.com/chair.jpg",
    "prefill"           => [
    "name"              => "",
    "email"             => "test@gmail.com",
    "contact"           => "6381211774",
    ],
    "notes"             => [
    "address"           => "Hello World",
    "merchant_order_id" => "12312321",
    ],
    "theme"             => [
    "color"             => "#red"
    ],
    "order_id"          => $razorpayOrderId,
];

if ($displayCurrency !== 'INR'){
    $data['display_currency']  = $displayCurrency;
    $data['display_amount']    = $displayAmount;
}

$json = json_encode($data);

require("checkout/{$checkout}.php");
```

[image]

Comment: well was `pay.php` called before so the session key would even exist?

Comment: @ArSeN no `pay.php` is called only once and session is created on call.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like the index actually is there. Where do you `var_dump()` that? And honestly I did not understand what you meant with your last comment - can you explain a bit which file is visited by the user at which point in time?

Comment: In what way are `pay.php` and `verify.php` connected? Where exactly is that form included?

Comment: @El_Vanja `pay.php` file sends data to `HTML` form and after successful payment `verify.php` file checks data for server with session  value `razorpay_payment_id`.

Comment: How do they interact? That part of the code is omitted in your question. What form is `pay.php` tied to? The one you showed in the question? And how is `verify.php` called after successful payment? How is successful payment even detected?

Comment: @El_Vanja `verify.php` is a call back url from form data. And none of the code is omitted, check github linked in question for more details

Comment: @sanojlawrence your code looks almost 1:1 like razorpay's example. Could you add your php.ini's cookie settings (`phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);` please? Search for `session.` and pass your options here? Additionally it would be helpful to have dev tool-headers here. Please add the `Set-Cookie` headers on the pay.php and the `Cookie` headers on the POST coming from the razorpay? My assumption is that you local setup `localhost:8000` has a mismatch with your `set-cookie` header and when coming back from razorpay it's simply empty and loads a new session.

Comment: @ChristophKluge do you want to paste entire `php.ini` file of which `session` `session.auto_start = 0` so on.

Comment: Yes please. Session config and cookie config is important here. Can you additionall tell us how you open the `pay.php` script? Is it: `http://localhost:8000/pay.php` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pay.php` or something else?

Comment: @ChristophKluge i really don't know which part your looking so here is php.ini file http://safebrowser.tk/php.ini , and i use `netbeans with wamp`  so this is how my url looks like `http://localhost:8000/pay.php`

Comment: I tried to reproduce it locally and everything works as expected. Are you a Firefox/Gecko user? Browsers are becoming more strict on misconfigured cookies. Can you try to set explicitly set the following settings for your local development? `session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', 'localhost', false, false);`. If this does not work, can you use a custom local entry inside your `/etc/hosts`? Something like `test-razorpay.local`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think the session exists in this flow. Or point out where was it stored in session.

Otherwise, use the same you would use for getting data out of a callback URL.

Have you tried

```
        $attributes = array(
            'razorpay_order_id' => $_POST['razorpay_order_id'],
            'razorpay_payment_id' => $_POST['razorpay_payment_id'],
            'razorpay_signature' => $_POST['razorpay_signature']
        );
```